# Opa Executable Not Being Created

Tags: compilation, executable, opa

When I go to compile something with Opa, whether it be something I've written, or even the really simple 'Hello, web!' script, I see that no executable is produced. It is producing a _build directory and a JavaScript file. Any idea what's happening here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest version of Opa compiles to JavaScript (running on Node.js). So the produced JavaScript file is exactly what you need and you should be able to run it with:

```
./your_app.js
```

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks! The .js file is actually a legitimate executable, no JavaScript itself. This is not exactly clear in Opa's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

yes, after you need exactly launch this javascript file, as like:

```
./application.js
```